# Crawling a Javascript heavy site with Ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-crawler, mechanize

I want to crawl/scrape a number of websites that heavily rely on Javascript, which my Mechanize agent (the one I normally use) can't handle, since it's unable to render the html. A good example is [this site](http://www.antvorskovskole.skoleintra.dk/Infoweb/Designskabelon_Slagelse/Rammeside.asp?Action=&Side=&Klasse=&Id=&Startside=&ForumID=).

Is there any way to get the rendered html output of that site from within a Ruby on Rails application?

I am using Ruby 2.0.0 and Rails 4.0.1

Comment: Maybe look into http://phantomjs.org

Comment: Your options are to figure out how to do it or switch to a full browser solution like selenium.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara) to do it. Here's a resource:

- http://www.chrisle.me/2012/12/scraping-html5-sites-using-capybara-phantomjs/

Or search Google for "Capybara" scraper.

One thing to note, performance will be awful. I have built such a scraper, and it was almost not worth it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm gonna investigate a solution of that kind.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **I-Macros** for webscraping. The site mentioned by you uses frames. so each frame can be treated as individual pages and scraped. As an alternative, you could use **simple java program using apache HttpClient/HtmlUnit** APIs.